# Using only Set Laws: Prove $(A-B) \cup (B-A) = (A \cup B)-(A \cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Is my proof my correct?

***Using only Set Laws: Prove $(A-B) \cup (B-A) = (A \cup B)-(A \cap B)$***

***Starting conditions***

$1)(A-B) \cup (B-A) =$

***Set difference definition***

$2)(A \cap B^C) \cup (B \cap A^C)=$

***Distributive laws***

$3)(B\cup (A \cap B^C)) \cap (A^C\cup (A \cap B^C))=$

***Distributive laws and universal set definition***

$4)(A \cup B)\cap (A^C \cup B^C)=$

***DeMorgan's laws***

$5)(A \cup B)\cap (A \cap B)^C=$

***Set difference definition***

$6)(A \cup B)-(A \cap B)$

***Q.E.D.***

Comment: Looks right!  Maybe split going from 3 to 4 into two steps ... or three

Comment: Thank you for your fast help! I am glad that my proof looks good in your opinion!

Comment: Well, can you show those extra steps?

Comment: I just saw that you already did it! Thank you!

Comment: So were you provided with some of those laws involving the universal set?  How were they defined, and what names were given to them?

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic comment! Universal set is a fascinating topic. I    know this law: $Domination$ $Law:$ $U \cup A = U.$ Additionally, universal set is connected with Russell's paradox. I was reading that to avoid Russell's paradox, a similar concept was discovered: universal objects that are not sets. "One difference between a universal set and a universal class is that the universal class does not contain itself, because proper classes cannot be elements of other classes.(Wikipedia)"

Comment: Other law that can be mentioned and that I used is the $Complement$ $Law:$ $A \cup A^C = U$

Comment: OK, so I used the Complement Law to go from 3.3 to 3.6. Domination (sometimes called Annihilation) is a handy law as well, yes! I used Identity to go from 3.6 to 4.0. Identity says that $X \cap U = X$ ... The $U$ works as the identity element for $\cap$, just as $1$ is the identity element for multiplication, and $\top$ the identity element for $\land$. Likewise, we have $X \cup \emptyset= X$, meaning that the empty set $\emptyset$ (which is $U^C$) is the identity element for $\cup$, just as $0$ is the identity element for addition, and $\bot$ the identity element for $\lor$.

Comment: Outstanding comment! I never had thought about the universal set as the identity element for intersection and the empty set as the identity element for union, I did not know either about T as the identity element for conjunction and the inverse T as the identity element for disjunction. Thank you so much! I am amazed and delighted!

Comment: Oh my! You're in a for a treat then: *all* laws for sets have exact equivalents on the propositional logic side. In fact, many have the same name. For example: in logic we have $A \land B \Leftrightarrow B \land A$, and in set theory we have $A \cap B \Leftrightarrow B \cap A$.  Indeed, you can take any law from set theory, and replace $\cap$ with $\land$, $\cup$ with $\lor$, and $X^C$  with $\neg X$, and you will get a true law for logic ... and vice versa. Indeed, the likeness of the symbols $\cap$ and $\land$ as well as $\cup$ and $\lor$ is no accident!

Comment: I do not know and I never thought about it!!! Thank you so much!!! You are fantastic professor and I am a very bad student! :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the step from 3 to 4 into a few more steps:

3. $(B\cup (A \cap B^C)) \cap (A^C \cup (A \cap B^C)) =$ (Distribution)

3.3. $(B\cup A) \cap (B \cup B^C) \cap (A^C \cup A) \cap (A^C \cup B^C) =$ (Complement)

3.6 $(B \cup A) \cap U \cap U \cap (A^C\cup B^C) =$ (Identity)

4. $(B \cup A) \cap (A^C\cup B^C)$

Answer (score 2):

All the steps appear to be correct, yes.  Maybe you can break the step from 3) to 4) into two steps, depending on the level of clarity required.